# Free-jqGrid navButtonAdd buttonColor

Tags: jquery, css, jqgrid, font-awesome, free-jqgrid

Using free-jqgrid v4.13.1 is there any parameter to set a button color while using fontAwesome? I can change an icon color by setting a style on it, but I'd like to know if there is a parameter in the `navButtonAdd` to set the icon color something like:

```
.jqGrid("navButtonAdd", {
    iconsOverText: true,
    caption:"<span class='ui-pg-button-text'>Filter</span>",
    buttonicon: "fa-filter",
```

> buttoncolor: "red",

```
        onClickButton: function() {
            InitializeFilterDialog();
            $("#filter-dialog-form").dialog("open");
        },
    title:"Filter",
    position: "first"
})
```

I know for other icons I could do something like:

```
filterButton.addClass("fa-ban");
filterButton.css("color", "red");
```

I am also wondering if there is a parameter on jqGrid that allows for setting the default button color, like:

```
iconSet: "fontAwesome",
```

> iconColor: "blue",

```
.....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's interesting question. Yes, everything is possible!

You need to define CSS rule like

```css
.red {
    color: red;
}
```

and to use

```js
buttonicon: "fa-table red"
```

instead of `buttonicon: "fa-filter"`.

See https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/7gfhyxgw/3/

[image]

To change the default colors of all buttons to blue you need to define some class like

```css
.myblue {
    color: blue;
}
```

Then one should define new `iconSet` based on existing `"fontAwesome"` like

```css
$.jgrid.icons.blueFontAwesome = {
    baseIconSet: "fontAwesome",
    common: "fa myblue",
    nav: {}
};
```

and to use `iconSet: "blueFontAwesome"` instead of `iconSet: "fontAwesome"`. s the result one get the results like on the next demo

https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/7gfhyxgw/4/

[image]

I changed the above rule for `red` color a little to increase its priority:

```css
.ui-pg-div .red {
    color: red;
}
```

REMARK: The usage of `nav: {}` seems be unneeded. It's required because of small bug which I will fix next days. The problem was: I tested extension of existing iconSet only for specific icons and never tested changing the `common` class.

Comment: That is a good idea to add a class and just add it to the buttonicon, maybe in the future a parameter could be added. Thanks again for your help Oleg

Comment: How would I get the pagination buttons to also change to the blueFontAwesome?

Comment: @Noctane: I think that the most easy way to change the color of **all icons** will be to define `$.jgrid.icons.blueFontAwesome` in another way: `$.jgrid.icons.blueFontAwesome = $.extend($.jgrid.icons.fontAwesome, { common: "fa myblue" });`. See the demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/7gfhyxgw/5/